# For the array I am getting values either 0 and 255 and nothing in between for matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am using this code:

```
for m_cof=1:3
    for n_cof=1:3
        Fixed_term=(((2*(m_cof-1)+1)*(2*(n_cof-1)+1))/(g(1)*g(2)));
        c(m_cof,n_cof)=0;
        for u=1:g(1)
            y=((2*u)/g(1));
            uof=Polynomial1(y,m_cof);
            for v=1:g(2)
                z=((2*v)/g(2));
                vof=Polynomial1(z,n_cof);
                f=f_template(u,v);
                iop=(Fixed_term*f_template(u,v)*uof*vof)
                c(m_cof,n_cof)=iop+c(m_cof,n_cof)
            end
        end
    end
end`
```

where `f_template` is RGB to grey image array, **but the contents of `c` are just 0 and 255 and nothing in between can you please help**?

Comment: Is your image type `uint8` (unsigned 8-bit integers)? If so, integer division will truncate the result to the nearest integer, and saturate at the min/max values of `0` and `255`. Try `Im = double(Im)` to convert to `double` before doing any calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are experiencing saturation due to the data type that your image belongs to.  To overcome this, cast your image to `double`, then try your code again.

Simply put, do this at the beginning of your code before the nested loops:

```
f_template = double(f_template);
```